# Xcode v 14 runtime error - dyld[34350]: Symbol not found:

Tags: charts, xcode14

I have just upgraded to Xcode v14.  I have had a few problems with charts code not compiling but have found solutions to these.  Now the code compiles but generates an abort with the following message:

dyld[34350]: Symbol not found: _$s6Charts10MarkerViewC14refreshContent5entry9highlightyAA14ChartDataEntryC_AA9HighlightCtF
Referenced from:  /Users/Myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/285CCF21-E22B-4FC5-B2E5-ABB5387A3F58/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4D921263-E886-41BF-9912-74488B20B228/My.app/My App Name
Expected in:     <02267E48-E846-3B65-AFA4-58BC5C84F5E2> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Charts.framework/Charts

I suspect this is to do with a runtime library not being found but I can't tell where the issue would be and how I can fix it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have the same problem, we are using Charts as Carthrage so we are not able to update it via podfile, any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this through [this very helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64657668/custom-framework-dyld-symbol-not-found-s11cryptoswift7paddingo5pkcs7ya2cmf).  I then received a number of compiler errors from code within the Charts pod.  These were resolved by making changes to Charts from these posts.

[Type 'ChartDataSet' does not conform to protocol 'RangeReplaceableCollection'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010925/charts-not-compile-on-xcode-14)

[Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a (Xcode 14.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574268/missing-file-libarclite-iphoneos-a-xcode-14-3) I changed the target IOS for Charts to 11.

[Xcode 14 Beta 1: the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/4838)